# How to implement multi-process in my example C code?

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, signal-processing

Starting with my background, I'm a beginner in C who is using a DAQ card with data streaming mode since we wanted it to acquire and analysis data infinitely. However, my calculation seems will retard the whole transfer speed even I have already optimized the code, which will caused FIFO overflow. Multi-process might be the solution to solve my problem because it can let my PC to turn on its all CPU (I got 8 cores) to boost up the calculation speed. I read some articles regarding how to write multi-process, such as `fork()` and `pipe`. But what I'm confusing is, how could I implement to my original script?

Here is a minimal example code to mimic my data calculation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{
    int i;
    const int u32Size = 62;
    float* ch1Buffer = NULL;
    float* ch2Buffer = NULL;
    float* Corrected=NULL;
    
    
    
    int pBuffer[] = { 0,10,1,10,1,10,0,10,2,10,3,10,4,10,5,10,4,10,3,10,2,10,1,10,0,10,0,10,1,10,2,10,3,10,4,10,5,10,4,10,3,10,2,10,0,10,2,10,3,10,4,10,5,10,4,10,3,10,2,10,1,10};
    int* pi16Buffer = pBuffer;


    
    // memory allocation
    ch1Buffer = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch1Buffer);
    ch2Buffer = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);
    Corrected = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof * Corrected);
    

    // De-interleave the data to ch1Buffer and ch2Buffer
    for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
    {
        ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
        ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
    }

    
    



    for (i = 0; i < u32Size / 2; i++) {
        Corrected[i] = ch1Buffer[i] / ch2Buffer[i];
    }
    
    

     // Print out to check the result
    for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++) {
        printf("Normalized Value=%f\n ", Corrected[i]);
        printf("Channel 2 data=%f\n ", ch2Buffer[i]);
        printf("Channel 1 data=%f\n ", ch1Buffer[i]);
    }

    free(ch1Buffer);
    free(ch2Buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The whole DAQ operation code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CsPrototypes.h>
#include "CsExpert.h"

#include "CsAppSupport.h"
#include "CsTchar.h"
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

#define OUT_FILE    "BufferSums.txt"            /* name of the output file */
#define LOOP_COUNT          1000
#define TRANSFER_TIMEOUT    10000
#define STM_SECTION _T("StmConfig")             /* section name in ini file */
#define MAX_SEGMENTS_COUNT  100000000           // Max number of segments in a single file
//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1
//length of complex array
#define N 1024  //data points need to do hilbert
uInt32 i, n;
int64 i64Sum = 0;
float max1 = 0;
float max2 = 0;
float Corrected = 0;
double AUC = 0;
//int16* ch1Buffer = NULL;
int16* ch2newBuffer = NULL;
int16* ch2Buffer = NULL;
fftw_complex(hilbertedch2[N]);
uInt8* pu8Buffer = NULL;
int16* pi16Buffer = NULL;


typedef struct
{
    uInt32      u32TransferTimeout;
    TCHAR       strResultFile[MAX_PATH];
    BOOL        bDoAnalysis;            /* Turn on or off data analysis */
}CSSTMCONFIG, *PCSSTMCONFIG;

int32 InitializeStream(CSHANDLE hSystem);
void hilbert(const int16* in, fftw_complex* out, fftw_plan plan_forward, fftw_plan plan_backward);
float SumBufferData(void* pBuffer, uInt32 u32Size, uInt32 u32SampleBits);
//float SumBufferData(void* pBuffer, uInt32 u32Size, uInt32 u32SampleBits);
void UpdateProgress(DWORD dwTickStart, uInt32 u32UpdateInterval, unsigned long long llSamples);
void SaveResults(float* i64Results, uInt32 u32Count, TCHAR* strFileName);
int32 LoadStmConfiguration(LPCTSTR szIniFile, PCSSTMCONFIG pConfig);


int _tmain()
{
    int32                       i32Status = CS_SUCCESS;
    void*                       pBuffer1 = NULL;
    void*                       pBuffer2 = NULL;
    void*                       pCurrentBuffer = NULL;
    void*                       pWorkBuffer = NULL;
    uInt32                      u32Mode;
    CSHANDLE                    hSystem = 0;
    CSSYSTEMINFO                CsSysInfo = {0};
    CSACQUISITIONCONFIG         CsAcqCfg = {0};
    CSSTMCONFIG                 StmConfig;
    LPCTSTR                     szIniFile = _T("Stream2Analysis.ini");
    BOOL                        bDone = FALSE;
    BOOL                        bErrorData = FALSE;
    uInt32                      u32LoopCount = 0;
    uInt32                      u32SaveCount = 0;
    uInt32                      u32TickStart = 0;
    long long                   llTotalSamples = 0;
    uInt32                      u32TransferSize = 0;
    uInt32                      u32DataSegmentInBytes = 0;
    uInt32                      u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes = 0;
    uInt32                      u32ErrorFlag = 0;
    //int64*                        pi64Sums;
    float* pi64Sums;
    uInt32                      u32ActualLength = 0;
    uInt8                       u8EndOfData = 0;
    BOOL                        bStreamCompletedSuccess = FALSE;
    uInt32                      u32SegmentTail_Bytes = 0;
    

    

    // Initializes the CompuScope boards found in the system. If the
    // system is not found a message with the error code will appear.
    // Otherwise i32Status will contain the number of systems found.
    i32Status = CsInitialize();



    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        return (-1);
    }

    // Get System. This sample program only supports one system. If
    // 2 systems or more are found, the first system that is found
    // will be the system that will be used. hSystem will hold a unique
    // system identifier that is used when referencing the system.
    i32Status = CsGetSystem(&hSystem, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        return (-1);
    }

    // Get System information. The u32Size field must be filled in
    // prior to calling CsGetSystemInfo
    CsSysInfo.u32Size = sizeof(CSSYSTEMINFO);
    i32Status = CsGetSystemInfo(hSystem, &CsSysInfo);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    if ( CsSysInfo.u32BoardCount > 1 )
    {
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("This sample program does not support CompuScope M/S system."));
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    // Display the system name from the driver
    _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nBoard Name: %s"), CsSysInfo.strBoardName);

    // In this example we're only using 1 trigger source
    i32Status = CsAs_ConfigureSystem(hSystem, (int)CsSysInfo.u32ChannelCount, 1, (LPCTSTR)szIniFile, &u32Mode);

    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        if (CS_INVALID_FILENAME == i32Status)
        {
            // Display message but continue on using defaults.
            _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nCannot find %s - using default parameters."), szIniFile);
        }
        else
        {   
            // Otherwise the call failed.  If the call did fail we should free the CompuScope
            // system so it's available for another application
            DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
            CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
            return(-1);
        }
    }

    // If the return value is greater than  1, then either the application, 
    // acquisition, some of the Channel and / or some of the Trigger sections
    // were missing from the ini file and the default parameters were used. 
    if (CS_USING_DEFAULT_ACQ_DATA & i32Status)
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nNo ini entry for acquisition. Using defaults."));

    if (CS_USING_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_DATA & i32Status)
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nNo ini entry for one or more Channels. Using defaults for missing items."));

    if (CS_USING_DEFAULT_TRIGGER_DATA & i32Status)
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nNo ini entry for one or more Triggers. Using defaults for missing items."));


    // Load application specific information from the ini file
    i32Status = LoadStmConfiguration(szIniFile, &StmConfig);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }
    if (CS_USING_DEFAULTS == i32Status)
    {
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nNo ini entry for Stm configuration. Using defaults."));
    }

    // Streaming Configuration
    // Validate if the board supports hardware streaming  If  it is not supported, 
    // we'll exit gracefully.
    i32Status = InitializeStream(hSystem);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        // Error string is displayed in InitializeStream
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    // Get user's acquisition data to use for various parameters for transfer
    CsAcqCfg.u32Size = sizeof(CSACQUISITIONCONFIG);
    i32Status = CsGet(hSystem, CS_ACQUISITION, CS_CURRENT_CONFIGURATION, &CsAcqCfg);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    // For this sample program only, check for a limited segment size
    if ( CsAcqCfg.i64SegmentSize < 0 || CsAcqCfg.i64Depth < 0 )
    {
        _ftprintf (stderr, _T("\n\nThis sample program does not support acquisitions with infinite segment size.\n"));
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    if ( CsAcqCfg.u32SegmentCount > MAX_SEGMENTS_COUNT )
    {
        _ftprintf (stderr, _T("\nSegment count too big  %d. Max segment count support = %d \n"), 
                    CsAcqCfg.u32SegmentCount, MAX_SEGMENTS_COUNT);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    // Allocate memory to keep the analysis results
    pi64Sums = (float *)calloc(CsAcqCfg.u32SegmentCount, sizeof(float));
    if (NULL == pi64Sums)
    {
        _ftprintf (stderr, _T("\nUnable to allocate memory to hold analysis results.\n"));
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    // In Streaming, some hardware related information are placed at the end of each segment. These samples contain also timestamp\
    // information for the segemnt. The number of extra bytes may be different depending on CompuScope card model.
    i32Status = CsGet( hSystem, 0, CS_SEGMENTTAIL_SIZE_BYTES, &u32SegmentTail_Bytes );
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        ExitThread(1);
    }


    // We need to allocate a buffer for transferring the data. Buffer is allocated as void with
    // a size of length * number of channels * sample size. All channels in the mode are transferred
    // within the same buffer, so the mode tells us the number of channels.  
    // The buffer must be allocated by a call to CsStmAllocateBuffer.  This routine will
    // allocate a buffer suitable for streaming.  In this program we're allocating 2 streaming buffers
    // so we can transfer to one while doing analysis on the other.
    u32DataSegmentInBytes = (uInt32)(CsAcqCfg.i64SegmentSize * CsAcqCfg.u32SampleSize *(CsAcqCfg.u32Mode & CS_MASKED_MODE));

    u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes = u32DataSegmentInBytes + u32SegmentTail_Bytes;

    // Round the buffersize to a 16 byte boundary. This is necessary for streaming.
    u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes = u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes/16*16 ;

    u32TransferSize = u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes/CsAcqCfg.u32SampleSize;
    _ftprintf (stderr, _T("\n(Actual buffer size used for data streaming = %u Bytes)\n"), u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes );

    i32Status = CsStmAllocateBuffer(hSystem, 0,  u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes, &pBuffer1);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        _ftprintf (stderr, _T("\nUnable to allocate memory for stream buffer 1.\n"));
        free(pi64Sums);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    i32Status = CsStmAllocateBuffer(hSystem, 0,  u32DataSegmentWithTailInBytes, &pBuffer2);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        _ftprintf (stderr, _T("\nUnable to allocate memory for stream buffer 2.\n"));
        CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer1);
        free(pi64Sums);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }


    // Commit the values to the driver.  This is where the values get sent to the
    // hardware.  Any invalid parameters will be caught here and an error returned.
    i32Status = CsDo(hSystem, ACTION_COMMIT);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        free(pi64Sums);
        CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer1);
        CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer2);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }

    printf ("\nStart streaming. Press ESC to abort\n\n");

    // Start the data acquisition
    i32Status = CsDo(hSystem, ACTION_START);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        free(pi64Sums);
        CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer1);
        CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer2);
        CsFreeSystem(hSystem);
        return (-1);
    }


    u32TickStart =  GetTickCount();

    // loop until either we've done the number of segments we want, or
    // the ESC key was pressed to abort. While we loop we transfer into
    // pCurrentBuffer and do our analysis on pWorkBuffer
    while( ! ( bDone || bStreamCompletedSuccess) )
    {
        // Determine where new data transfer data will go. We alternate
        // between our 2 DMA buffers
        if (u32LoopCount & 1)
        {
            pCurrentBuffer = pBuffer2;
        }
        else
        {
            pCurrentBuffer = pBuffer1;
        }

        i32Status = CsStmTransferToBuffer(hSystem, 0, pCurrentBuffer, u32TransferSize);
        if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
        {
            DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
            break;
        }

        if ( StmConfig.bDoAnalysis )
        {
            if ( NULL != pWorkBuffer )
            {
                pi64Sums[u32SaveCount++] = SumBufferData(pWorkBuffer, u32DataSegmentInBytes/CsAcqCfg.u32SampleSize, CsAcqCfg.u32SampleBits);
            }
        }
        // Wait for the DMA transfer on the current buffer to complete so we can loop 
        // back around to start a new one. Calling thread will sleep until
        // the transfer completes
        i32Status = CsStmGetTransferStatus( hSystem, 0, StmConfig.u32TransferTimeout, &u32ErrorFlag, &u32ActualLength, &u8EndOfData );
        if ( CS_SUCCEEDED(i32Status) )
        {
            llTotalSamples += u32TransferSize;
            bStreamCompletedSuccess = (0 != u8EndOfData);
        }
        else
        {
            bDone = TRUE;
            if ( CS_STM_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT == i32Status )
            {
                // Timeout on CsStmGetTransferStatus().
                // Data Stransfer has not yet completed. We can repeat calling CsStmGetTransferStatus()  until the function
                // returns the status CS_SUCCESS.
                // In this sample program, we just stop and return the error.
                DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
            }
            else /* some other error */
            {
                DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
            }
        }

        pWorkBuffer = pCurrentBuffer;

        u32LoopCount++;

        // Are we being asked to quit? 
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            switch (toupper(_getch()))
            {
            case 27: 
                bDone = TRUE;
                break;
            default:
                MessageBeep(MB_ICONHAND);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Show on the screen the result in every about 900ms sec 
        UpdateProgress(u32TickStart, 900, llTotalSamples);
    }

    // Show on the screen the final result
    _ftprintf (stdout, _T("\n"));
    UpdateProgress(u32TickStart, 0, llTotalSamples);

    // Abort the current acquisition 
    CsDo(hSystem, ACTION_ABORT);

    // Because the loop count above tests at the start of the loop, we may break the loop
    // while there's still data in pWorkBuffer to analyze. That would be the last data transferred
    // into pBuffer2
    if ( StmConfig.bDoAnalysis )
    {
        if ( u32SaveCount < CsAcqCfg.u32SegmentCount )
        {
            pi64Sums[u32SaveCount++] = SumBufferData(pWorkBuffer, u32DataSegmentInBytes/CsAcqCfg.u32SampleSize, CsAcqCfg.u32SampleBits);
        }
    }

    // Free all buffers that have been allocated. Buffers allocated with
    // CsStmAllocateBuffer must be freed with CsStmFreeBuffer
    CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer1);
    CsStmFreeBuffer(hSystem, 0, pBuffer2);

    // Free the CompuScope system and any resources it's been using
    i32Status = CsFreeSystem(hSystem);

    if (bErrorData)
    {
        _ftprintf (stdout, _T("\nStream aborted on error.\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        if ( u32LoopCount < CsAcqCfg.u32SegmentCount )
        {
            _ftprintf (stdout, _T("\nStream aborted by user or error.\n"));
        }
        else
        {
            _ftprintf (stdout, _T("\nStream has finsihed %u loops.\n"), CsAcqCfg.u32SegmentCount);
        }
    }

    // print out our list of sums to a file
    if (u32SaveCount > 0)
    {
        SaveResults(pi64Sums, u32SaveCount, StmConfig.strResultFile);
    }
    
    free(pi64Sums);
    return 0;
}


int32 InitializeStream(CSHANDLE hSystem)
{
    int32   i32Status = CS_SUCCESS;
    int64   i64ExtendedOptions = 0; 

    CSACQUISITIONCONFIG CsAcqCfg = {0};

    CsAcqCfg.u32Size = sizeof(CSACQUISITIONCONFIG);

    // Get user's acquisition Data
    i32Status = CsGet(hSystem, CS_ACQUISITION, CS_CURRENT_CONFIGURATION, &CsAcqCfg);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        return (i32Status);
    }

    // Check if selected system supports Expert Stream
    // And set the correct image to be used.
    CsGet(hSystem, CS_PARAMS, CS_EXTENDED_BOARD_OPTIONS, &i64ExtendedOptions);

    if (i64ExtendedOptions & CS_BBOPTIONS_STREAM)
    {
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nSelecting Expert Stream from image 1."));
        CsAcqCfg.u32Mode |= CS_MODE_USER1;
    }
    else if ((i64ExtendedOptions >> 32) & CS_BBOPTIONS_STREAM)
    {
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nSelecting Expert Stream from image 2."));
        CsAcqCfg.u32Mode |= CS_MODE_USER2;
    }
    else
    {
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nCurrent system does not support Expert Stream."));
        _ftprintf(stdout, _T("\nApplication terminated."));
        return CS_MISC_ERROR;
    }
    
    // Sets the Acquisition values down the driver, without any validation, 
    // for the Commit step which will validate system configuration.
    i32Status = CsSet(hSystem, CS_ACQUISITION, &CsAcqCfg);
    if (CS_FAILED(i32Status))
    {
        DisplayErrorString(i32Status);
        return CS_MISC_ERROR;
    }

    return CS_SUCCESS; // Success
}


void UpdateProgress( DWORD  dwTickStart, uInt32 u32UpdateInterval_ms, unsigned long long llSamples )
{
    static  DWORD   dwTickLastUpdate = 0;
    uInt32  h, m, s;
    DWORD   dwElapsed;
    DWORD   dwTickNow = GetTickCount();


    if ((dwTickNow - dwTickLastUpdate > u32UpdateInterval_ms))
    {
        double dRate;

        dwTickLastUpdate = dwTickNow;
        dwElapsed = dwTickNow - dwTickStart;

        if (dwElapsed)
        {
            dRate = (llSamples / 1000000.0) / (dwElapsed / 1000.0);
            h = m = s = 0;
            if (dwElapsed >= 1000)
            {
                if ((s = dwElapsed / 1000) >= 60)   // Seconds
                {
                    if ((m = s / 60) >= 60)         // Minutes
                    {
                        if ((h = m / 60) > 0)       // Hours
                            m %= 60;
                    }

                    s %= 60;
                }
            }
            printf ("\rTotal data: %0.2f MS, Rate: %6.2f MS/s, Elapsed Time: %u:%02u:%02u  ", llSamples / 1000000.0, dRate, h, m, s);
        }
    }
}
//void hilbert(const int16* in, fftw_complex* out)
void hilbert(const int16* in, fftw_complex* out, fftw_plan plan_forward, fftw_plan plan_backward)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    //fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_forward);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
    int hN = N>>1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    //plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_backward);
    // do some cleaning
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
    //fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }
}


float SumBufferData(void* pBuffer, uInt32 u32Size, uInt32 u32SampleBits)
{
    // In this routine we sum up all the samples in the buffer. This function 
    // should be replaced with the user's analysys function


    if ( 8 == u32SampleBits )
    {
        pu8Buffer = (uInt8 *)pBuffer;
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++)
        {
            i64Sum += pu8Buffer[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pi16Buffer = (int16 *)pBuffer;
        
        
        
        //fftw_complex(hilbertedch2[N]);
        fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, hilbertedch2, hilbertedch2, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_plan plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, hilbertedch2, hilbertedch2, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    
    
        //ch1Buffer     = (int16*)calloc(u32Size/2, sizeof*ch1Buffer);
        ch2Buffer = (int16*)calloc(u32Size / 2, sizeof * ch2Buffer);
        ch2newBuffer= (int16*)calloc(u32Size/2, sizeof* ch2newBuffer);
        

        // Divide ch1 and ch2 data from pi16Buffer
        //for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        //{
            //ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2];
            //ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2+1];
        
        //}
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2 ; i++)
        {
            ch2Buffer[i] = pi16Buffer[i*2+1];

        }

        // Pick out the data points range that we are interested
        memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[6944], 1024 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));
        // Do the hilbert transform to these data points
        hilbert(ch2newBuffer, hilbertedch2, plan_forward, plan_backward);
        fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
        fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);

        
        //Find max value in each segs of ch1 and ch2
        for (i = 128; i < 200 ; i++)
        {
            if (pi16Buffer[i*2] > max1)
                max1 = pi16Buffer[i*2];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            if (fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]) > max2)
                max2 = fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
        }
        
        Corrected = max2 / max1; // Calculate the signal correction

        //if (Corrected > 0.1)  // check the threshold and calculate area under curve
            //AUC += Corrected;
        //else
            //AUC = 0;
        
    
        
        
    }
    free(ch2Buffer);
    free(ch2newBuffer);
    return Corrected;
}
    void SaveResults(float * pi64Results, uInt32 u32Count, TCHAR * strFileName)
    //void SaveResults(float* pi64Results, uInt32 u32Count, TCHAR* strFileName)
 {
    FILE *pFile = 0;
    uInt32 i    = 0;
    TCHAR* fileType = ".txt";

    strcat(strFileName, fileType);
    pFile = _tfopen(strFileName, "w");
    //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("Loop\tRatio\n"));
    //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("Ratio\n"));
    for (i = 0; i < u32Count; i++)
    {
        //if (pi64Results[i] <= 0.1) // Print out the AUC value if it over the threshold
            //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("%f\n"), pi64Results[i]); 
            //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("%s\n"), "");
        //else
            //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("%f\n"), pi64Results[i]);
        _ftprintf(pFile, _T("%f\n"), pi64Results[i]);
        //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("  %u\t%I64d\n"), i+1, pi64Results[i]);
        //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("  %f\n"), pi64Results[i]);
        //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("  %u\t%f\t%f\t\t%f\n"), i + 1, pi64Results[i], testCh1, testCh2);
        //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("  %u\t%f\t%f\t\t%f\n"), i + 1, pi64Results[i], testCh1, testCh2);
        //_ftprintf(pFile, _T("  %u\t%f\t%f\t%f\n"), i + 1, pi64Results[i]);
    }
    fclose(pFile);
}


int32 LoadStmConfiguration(LPCTSTR szIniFile, PCSSTMCONFIG pConfig)
{
    TCHAR   szDefault[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR   szString[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR   szFilePath[MAX_PATH];
    int     nDummy;

    CSSTMCONFIG CsStmCfg;   

    // Set defaults in case we can't read the ini file
    CsStmCfg.u32TransferTimeout = TRANSFER_TIMEOUT;
    strcpy(CsStmCfg.strResultFile, _T(OUT_FILE));
    
    if (NULL == pConfig)
    {
        return (CS_INVALID_PARAMETER);
    }

    GetFullPathName(szIniFile, MAX_PATH, szFilePath, NULL);

    if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == GetFileAttributes(szFilePath))
    {
        *pConfig = CsStmCfg;
        return (CS_USING_DEFAULTS);
    }

    if (0 == GetPrivateProfileSection(STM_SECTION, szString, 100, szFilePath))
    {
        *pConfig = CsStmCfg;
        return (CS_USING_DEFAULTS);
    }

    nDummy = 0;
    CsStmCfg.bDoAnalysis = (0 != GetPrivateProfileInt(STM_SECTION, _T("DoAnalysis"), nDummy, szFilePath));

    nDummy = CsStmCfg.u32TransferTimeout;
    CsStmCfg.u32TransferTimeout = GetPrivateProfileInt(STM_SECTION, _T("TimeoutOnTransfer"), nDummy, szFilePath);

    _stprintf(szDefault, _T("%s"), CsStmCfg.strResultFile);
    GetPrivateProfileString(STM_SECTION, _T("ResultsFile"), szDefault, szString, MAX_PATH, szFilePath);
    _tcscpy(CsStmCfg.strResultFile, szString);

    *pConfig = CsStmCfg;
    return (CS_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Your issues are more likely with how you are reading data from the DAQ itself versus this level of processing - although you could look for "openmp" to parallelize your processing loops without the learning curve of fork().

Comment: OT: Why do you use `+=` instead of just `=` ? Why do you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Comment: OT: Why do you have two loops? One should do.

Comment: OT: Why do you allocate twice the memory needed?

Comment: Is your calculation just this simple division: `ch1Buffer[i] / ch2Buffer[i];` ?

Comment: Why do you need `ch1Buffer` and `ch2Buffer` ? Just take data directly from `p`

Comment: From the posted code it seems your calculation is really just 31 divisions. Splitting that to 8 cores will probably not help due to the overhead of handling multiple processes.

Comment: OT: `free(Corrected );` ?

Comment: @4386427 This is just a minimal example for testing. I am going to use the card with dual channels, keep obtaining data from both simultaneously. The rule to fill up the buffer is `ch1ch2ch1ch2....`, which means that `ch1` is located in odd index, `ch2` is even so I used `for` loop to de-interleave from the `pi16Buffer[i]`.
1. `+=` or `=` is no reason, I just follow the code from the card company, also the `calloc`. If  `malloc` could make them quicker, I would like to try. 
2. My bad, forgot to add `free(Corrected );`

Comment: @Kevin I think you have simplified the code too much. We need to see the endless loop an exactly what is inside.

Comment: @4386427 How much code do you want to see? Only for the data calculation and processing part? If you want to see the code to operate whole DAQ system, it will become 500+ lines of code. But I am fine with that if you want.

Comment: @Kevin The important thing is to see the main-loop where the data calculation takes place. I assume the DAQ system must be read by a single thread/process which handles data to the other threads.

Comment: @4386427 I've read it, didn't see any code like you mentioned, but I am just a beginner in C maybe they did already. Please find the updated code in my post which is around 700+ lines of code.

Comment: @4386427 The function `hilbert()` and `SumBufferData` are the calculation and analysis.